# How does QSocketNotifier really work?

Tags: c++, qt, gpio

I'm working with a `QSocketNotifier` on a GPIO to read on a SPI line. When the value of the GPIO change, the line is available for reading.

The main issue is that the `activate()` signal is always triggered. It seems that the behavior of `QSocketNotifier` isn't what I expected. It's more like "call `activate()` when the fd has someting in it." instead of "call `activate()` when the fd changes.". The GPIO is to the high level by default.

Am I right?

Comment: Why not reading the docs? It's explained in detail there when the activated() signal is emitted: 

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsocketnotifier.html

BTW you should precise what you mean by "fd changes" that you want to be notified about.

Comment: I read the doc and i've seen nothing about that. I mean by "fd changes" that the read value switches from `1` to `0` or from `x` to `y` for example. In my experience the `activated()` signal is always triggered even when the GPIO input doesn't change.

Comment: QSocketNotifier doesn't look at the content of the data coming out of the socket; rather it emits activate() when there is data ready to read, regardless of what the data is.

Comment: You can always read data on a GPIO (a `QFile` BTW) so how does it make sense?

Comment: Nevertheless you've missed some points in the docs. They've explicitly written that activated() is sent every time the data is ready to be read or written - not a word about checking the actual content. I can imagine that if you have multiple threads trying to write, the fd might not be ready to write to. Also, you can always read data, but there might be no data to be read at a specific moment.

Comment: My issue is that the `activate()` signal is always triggered. I'm guessing why and finding how to fix that. The documentation of QFile explains that a file handle can be used with `QSocketNotifier`. I expected the same behavior than the `poll()` or `select()` C functions.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue; did you find a solution?

Comment: No I just got rid of it and ended up using a devicetree based driver.